# change key of the multi-array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Have an array:

```
 $a =array[
      "param1"=>[]
      "param2"=>[]
      "param3"=>[]
      ]
function def($param){
      return $param.date();
}
```

want return a new array

```
  $a =array[
      def(param1)=>[]
      def(param2)=>[]
      def(param3)=>[]
      ]
```

anybody know how to do this?

Comment: What happen when your array contains `13` and `31` as keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

This is a pretty lengthy (and dirty) suggestion and there's probably a better way using one of [PHP's array methods](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php), but here goes:

```
$array = array('123' => 'should be 6', '14' => 'should be 5', '12' => 'should be 3');
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        $key_exp = str_split($key);
        $new_key = 0;
        foreach ($key_exp as $key_int) $new_key += $key_int;
        $new_array[$new_key] = $val;
}
```

Gives this output as expected:

```
array(3) {
  [6]=>
  string(11) "should be 6"
  [5]=>
  string(11) "should be 5"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "should be 3"
}
```

Note that you may, and probably will, run into key collisions using this method.

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
$out_array = array_fill_keys(array_map(function($in) {
  // do stuff you need
  return $out;
}, array_keys($in_array)), array());
```